# Delete statement raises deadlock

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have the following tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].Messages
    (
        [ID]            INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
        [Token]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL,
        [SubmitTime]    DATETIME DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()) NOT NULL,
        [ClientID]      INT                 NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Messages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
    );
    GO
    CREATE INDEX IX_Messages_ClientID ON dbo.Messages ([ClientID]) INCLUDE ([Token], [SubmitTime]);
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].Limit
    (
        [ClientID]          INT                 NOT NULL,
        Number              SMALLINT            NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Limit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ClientID] ASC)
    )
    GO
    CREATE INDEX IX_Limit_Number ON dbo.Limit (Number)
    GO
```

The data in tables could be like the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Messages (Token, SubmitTime, ClientID) VALUES
(NEWID(),GETUTCDATE(),1),
(NEWID(),GETUTCDATE(),2),
(NEWID(),GETUTCDATE(),3),
(NEWID(),GETUTCDATE(),1),
(NEWID(),GETUTCDATE(),1),
(NEWID(),GETUTCDATE(),1)

INSERT INTO Limit (ClientID, Number) VALUES
(1,2),
(2,0),
(3,1)
```

And the following code from ChildProc seems to be self blocking:

```
    DECLARE @Limit INT = 2
    
    DECLARE @MessagesOutput TABLE 
    (
        [Token]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        [ClientID]  INT
    )

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Limit
    CREATE TABLE #Limit ([ClientID] INT)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Messages)
    BEGIN
        -- get clients which have reached limits
        INSERT INTO #Limit ([ClientID])
        SELECT  [ClientID]
        FROM    dbo.Limit
        WHERE   Number >= @Limit
        
        DELETE  qp
        OUTPUT  deleted.[Token], deleted.[ClientID]
        INTO    @MessagesOutput ([Token], [ClientID])
        FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP 1
                    qp.[Token],
                    qp.[ClientID]
            FROM    dbo.Messages AS qp --WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
            WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Limit AS qu WHERE qu.[ClientID] = qp.[ClientID])
            ORDER BY qp.SubmitTime ASC
            --ORDER BY qp.ID ASC
        ) AS qp
        --OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
        
        -- another code
    END
```

Deadlock report:

```
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="p1"/>
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="p1" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 9:72057594134593536 (b8478435babd)" waittime="4691" ownerId="1539540879" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2022-10-26T18:15:26.630" XDES="0x21c0d0cc040" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="14468" status="suspended" spid="137" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-10-26T18:15:26.623" lastbatchcompleted="2022-10-26T18:15:26.623" lastattention="2022-10-26T18:12:00.613" clientapp="xxx" hostname="xxx" hostpid="3392" loginname="xxx" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1539540879" currentdb="9" currentdbname="xxx" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="ChildProc" line="45" stmtstart="3000" stmtend="3818" sqlhandle=x>DELETE qp OUTPUT deleted.[Token], deleted.[ClientID] INTO @MessagesOutput ([Token], [ClientID]) FROM ( SELECT TOP 1 qp.[Token], qp.[ClientID] FROM dbo.Messages AS qp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Limit AS qu WHERE qu.[ClientID] = qp.[ClientID]) ORDER BY qp.[SubmitTime] ASC ) AS q</frame>
                <frame procname="ParentProc" line="10" stmtstart="540" stmtend="756" sqlhandle=x>EXEC dbo.ChildProc</frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>xxx</inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="p2" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 9:000 (795eab8e26da)" waittime="4691" ownerId="1539540827" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2022-10-26T18:15:26.623" XDES="0x219c9ecc040" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="12528" status="suspended" spid="151" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-10-26T18:15:26.623" lastbatchcompleted="2022-10-26T18:15:26.627" lastattention="2022-10-26T18:07:58.700" clientapp="xxx" hostname="xxx" hostpid="5936" loginname="xxx" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1539540827" currentdb="9" currentdbname="xxx" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="ChildProc" line="45" stmtstart="3000" stmtend="3818" sqlhandle=x>DELETE qp OUTPUT deleted.[Token], deleted.[ClientID] INTO @MessagesOutput ([Token], [ClientID]) FROM ( SELECT TOP 1 qp.[Token], qp.[ClientID] FROM dbo.Messages AS qp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Limit AS qu WHERE qu.[ClientID] = qp.[ClientID]) ORDER BY qp.[SubmitTime] ASC ) AS q</frame>
                <frame procname="ParentProc" line="10" stmtstart="540" stmtend="756" sqlhandle=x>EXEC dbo.ChildProc</frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>xxx</inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594134593536" dbid="9" objectname="Messages" indexname="PK_Messages" id="lock20e2e27eb80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594134593536">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="p2" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="p1" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="000" dbid="9" objectname="Messages" indexname="IX_Messages_ClientID" id="lock20d6d67b200" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594134659072">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="p1" mode="U"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="p2" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

After changing SubmitTime to ID column execution plan becomes a bit better, but still can see Clustered index scans. So it not seems the best.
[image: execution plan after changing SubmitTime to ID column]

This sproc should delete first message from Messages for client which is not reached limit. Sproc is calling from two sessions in a row (so a bunch of calls from different sessions). Sproc is not calling inside transactions. Table usually have 100-400 rows in the begin of calling sproc
However, sometimes I can see deadlocks.

Found that SubmitTime column is not used anywhere, so we can easily change it in query to ID (PK of Messages). Tried CTE instead of subquery, but execution plan is the same.
Not sure about MAXDOP and UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE options, so would like to understand whether it correct path for investigation or not.
Also, I can't reproduce this deadlock.

**Any thoughts how to fix deadlock issue?**

Will appreciate for any help with it.

Comment: From a quick glance, you really don't need the `Id` column, your index with the include is extremely redundant (it's an inversion of the entire table) - instead of deleting one record, you'd have to delete both.  In the interim, just make the PK on `Messages` `(ClientId, Token, SubmitTime, Id)` with the longer term goal of removing `Id`.  Additionally, you don't need the temp table.  Just delete from `Messages` with the predicate `WHERE ClientId IN (SELECT ClientId FROM dbo.Limit WHERE Number >= @Limit)`

Comment: @bbaird, I've made little changes in description, so we can better see which data is stored in tables. I need deleted Token and ClientID for the following after delete queries, so I do need temp table or some mechanism to get this data. Also provided WHERE clause is not useful in my case because I need to delete only first row ( and we may have more than 1 token per client). Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I don't think your delete statement is even doing what you want it to - please look over this fiddle and see if it gets you closer to where you want to be: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7a642